# simulate random variable and transform of random variable

Tags: r, probability, distributions, random-variable, simulation

I have two random variables $X, Y$.

$X \sim  N(0,1) \qquad\text{(normally distributed)}\\
Y = g(X) \qquad\text{(g is a function such as g(x) = 1 + x + 2x^2)}$

I would like to draw a sample of size 1000 of X and Y. Do I need to draw from normal distribution for x and y or just for x and then use it in y? (See code examples for clarification.) In my case version 2 would suit me better, but I am not sure if this is still satisfies my definition of X and Y.

**Version 1**

```
m = 1000
x = rnorm(m, 0, 1)
y = g(x)
```

**Version 2**

```
m = 1000
x = rnorm(m, 0, 1)
y = g(rnorm(m, 0, 1))
```

**Which version is correct?**

Comment: You should use version 1. Version 2 will generate $m$ new random variables, not necessarily corresponding to $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(answer largely copied from comments)
You should use version 1. Version 2 will generate $m$ new random variables, not necessarily corresponding to $X$. With version 2 you get the correct *marginal* distributions, but the *joint* distribution is wrong. With version 1 both are right.